# AOSP flahed to android emulator

Tags: flash, emulation, android-source

I complied the source code of the aosp_arm-eng, and hope to flash it into an android emulator, does anyone knew how to do it?

Since the compliing prcess happened in an AWS EC2 server, basically I want fetched the images from the cloud and flash to the local emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is official documentation for the same

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd#sharing_avd_system_images_for_others_to_use_with_android_studio